# Sharepoint 2013 Foundation Application Web stuck on Upgrading

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Not sure what happened, but the SharePoint Foundation Application Web service is stuck on "Upgrading" status.

Browsing the site gives a 404. Tried restarting IIS, AppPools etc.

Have no clue how to resolve - I did try running the following command:

```
stsadm -o provisionservice -action start -servicetype spwebservice
```

This has not helped - any assistance much appreciated!

thanks.

Comment: Did you apply any patch? Are automatic windows update enabled? Try to restart the timer and admin service on server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having any issues with the SP timer job on that server?  We have the same issue and I believe its related to the timer job not responding.